# Methods to determine the range and domain of functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having difficulty trying to determine the range and domain of functions such as $f(x) = \sqrt{1 − 2 \sin x}$ or $f(x) = (x − 8)^{−1/3}$ I know the domain of $\sin(x)$ is $(-\infty , + \infty)$ and it's range is $1$ and $-1$ but the presence of the square root really confuses me and I don't know how to sketch the graph of this function to visualize it. Similarly with $f(x) = (x − 8)^{−1/3}$ I don't know how to sketch it to determine its range and domain. Is there an effective method in sketching and determining these types of functions??
Thanks!

Comment: Think about when $f(x) = \sqrt{1 - 2 \sin x}$ is well-defined for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We want $1 - 2 \sin x \ge 0$, i.e., $\sin x \le \frac{1}{2}$. For which $x$ is this true? Looking at a unit circle helps tremendously. As for the range, it is clear $f(x) = \sqrt{1 - 2 \sin x}$ has a minimum of $0$ (where?), and we can find the maximum by finding the max of $1 - 2 \sin x$. Recall $-1 \le \sin x \le 1$.

Comment: And for the second function, you can easily see that the domain is $\Bbb R$. You can write the function as $f(x) = \frac{1}{(x-8)^\frac13}$. The range and domain of the cube root is $\Bbb R$. Hence $f(x)$ is defined at all points where $(x-8)$ is defined except at $(x-8)=0 \implies x = 8$. Thus, the domain is $\Bbb R ~ \{8\}$ and the range is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @NilabroSaha Except there is no $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$ so the range is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.